Varnish returns outdated object on the first request
I cache JSON files stored on my server using Varnish-Cache.
Those JSONs are changed time to time and I have corresponding VCL config for them:
sub vcl_backend_response {  
    set beresp.ttl = 1s;
    set beresp.grace = 99y;
}

My target is to return always a fresh copy of the file and pass stale (grace) copy only AFTER the backend fails to serve this file (e.g. server is down).
Unfortunately, even after 1 hour of no-request to JSON file (via Varnish), the first requester of the file will receive an outdated copy (immediately from Varnish cache, staled object), then Varnish will update the cached object in the background and return it only on the second request.
I've read that this is the default behavior of Varnish.
But how can I change it?

The beresp.grace value is Varnish's interpretation of Stale While Revalidate, we use it to serve stale content while an asynchronous revalidation takes place.
You happen to be looking for a Stale If Error implementation, which Varnish doesn't support out of the box. As you hinted, we're going to (ab)use Grace for that.
beresp.grace vs req.grace
My suggestion is to set beresp.grace quite high, as you've done in your example. This ensures the object is long enough in the cache to handle a potential outage.
As long as the backend is healthy, you want to lower the grace. That is possible through the req.grace variable, which is available in the client context, whereas beresp.grace is available in the backend context.
The VCL code
Here's the code you need to set the object's grace, check the backend health, and potentially lower the tolerated grace:
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend server1 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .max_connections = 100;
    .probe = {
        .request =
            "HEAD / HTTP/1.1"
            "Host: localhost"
            "Connection: close"
            "User-Agent: Varnish Health Probe";
        .interval  = 10s;
        .timeout   = 5s;
        .window    = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
    .connect_timeout        = 5s;
    .first_byte_timeout     = 90s;
    .between_bytes_timeout  = 2s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        set req.grace = 0s;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 99y;
}

The std.healthy(req.backend_hint) call will check whether the backend is healthy. In that case, the used grace is reduced to zero.
Health checks are important
In order to return an accurate health check, the backend needs a health probe. That's why the VCL snippet has an elaborate health check assigned to it, with a bunch of timeout definitions.
By customizing the probing request, setting the probing interval, the timeout, window & threshold, you have a solid way to determine success criteria. The other timeouts also contribute to this.
Without a health probe, Varnish will only use the administrative health status that you can set in varnishadm. You can actively set that to true or false, that's why the probe is so important for real-time health checking.
You might run out of storage memory
By setting such a high grace value, objects are going to stay around much longer than their TTL allows them to. You will see in increase in memory usage.
If Varnish runs out of available cache storage, it will nuke objects to create free space based on a least recently used algorithm.
If that happens, the MAIN.n_lru_nuked counter in varnishstat will increase.
You can keep track of the memory you use for storage through the g_space and g_bytes counters in the SMA section of varnishstat.
There are 3 ways to handle this situation:

You tolerate the nuked objects and accept the fact that useful ones might disappear from the cache
You add memory to your server to increase the size of the cache
You lower the Grace from 99y to a more realistic value


Unfortunately, in your example if the backend is healthy but returns a 5xx error, there is no way to return the cached object instead of an error. I've also haven't found a feature to return to "vcl_recv" from "vcl_backend_error" (there is a "retry" call, but it retries the backend request, not the Varnish processing).
P. S.: I will not have any memory problems because I'm using "fellow" driver to keep whole the cache on disk.

@DanSpirit you're right about that. Eventually the health probe will return an unhealthy status, but it is possible that a user gets that 500 error before the health probe considers the backend to be unhealthy. You can minimize the risk by turning the health probe interval, the window & threshold settings. It's clear that Varnish Cache doesn't have a true "stale-if-error" mechanism. That's why we created "vmod_stale" in Varnish Enterprise: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-enterprise/vmods/stale/, allowing you to rearm objects in case of 500-style errors.
